# How to provide regular expression pattern while executing copy into command to select the files with a fixed prefix?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In case we have a files TEST_Code.csv and XmlTEST_Code.csv, Copy into command should select only the file which starts with TEST. The second files should not be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend testing your regular expression pattern on the LIST command before using it in the COPY INTO command. Your pattern would look like this:

```
list @MY_STAGE pattern = 'TEST.*';
```

If that works the way you want it, add `pattern = 'TEST.*'` to your COPY INTO command.